# ExtJS - convert json to Model

Tags: json, extjs, model

I have a json string that I need to map into a Model, I've been checking this json reader, Ext.data.reader.JsonView, but it seems that it only wokrs with a proxy, I need to pass a string (which contains the json) and map it to my model. Is that possible?

Thanks,
Angelo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look on the Ext.data.model's constructor. 
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-constructor
You can pass your data into it and it will map it to your model's fields. So you can do something like:

```
var model = new Ext.data.model(Ext.decode(<yourJsonString>));
```

`Ext.data.model` can be replaced with your model class.